# SQL Row roll up and concatenate strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, partitioning, accumulate

I have a table like this in SQL Server:

| ID | Rank | Tag | Name | Size | Seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |  | One | 14 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | A | Two | 12 | 4 |
| 3 | 2 | B | Three | 0 | 5 |
| 4 | 2 | C | Four | 0 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 |  | Five | 8 | 1 |
| 6 | 4 | A | Six | 18 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | B | Seven | 0 | 3 |

- "ID" is an identity field.
- Rank is an always increasing integer that does the same job as "Tag"
- "Tag" groups rows together into Single or Multiple type rows: if "Tag" is blank or null the row is selected by itself (single). If 'A', 'B' 'C' or 'D' they must all be rolled up to one 'A' (Multiple) row by concatenating the "Name" fields separated by commas.
- The "Size" value for the rolled-up rows is the value for the 'A' row. For all rows with 'B','C' or 'D' Size is zero and on rollup will take on the previous 'A' value.
- Finally, the Seq field is a user-specified sort order value the final ORDER BY Field.

So, I need the following output:

| Tag | Name | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Five | 8 |
| A | Six,Seven | 18 |
| A | Two,Three,Four | 12 |
|  | One | 14 |

I know I need sub queries and some combinations of GROUP BY and/or PARTITION BY, plus ROW_OVER to roll up the rows. I've tried all combinations I can think of with no success. There must be TSQL query to do this without resorting to cursors.  Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1):

```
select   min(tag)               as tag
        ,string_agg(name, ', ') as name
        ,sum(size)              as size
from     t
group by rank
```

| tag | name | size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| null | One | 14 |
| A | Two, Three, Four | 12 |
| null | Five | 8 |
| A | Six, Seven | 18 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/aVzhuIhD)

Comment: This works on the sample data. I'm not sure the `sum(size)` column would always hold for live data, and I'm not sure the tag names are real tag names vs just examples, where  `min(tag)` might not be good enough on real data.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I just looked over the data again and I'm not sure why it wouldn't work. He wants the sum for all the As grouped by rank and he always wants A as the tag which is the min value alphabetically.

Comment: My point is that it does work on the sample data. I agree with you there. But this sample data itself seems substantially contrived vs his probable actual data in ways that might (might! -- not a guarantee, I know) break the query in production.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the requirements, I seems we are grouping by the `rank` column. Additionally, some of the fields are determined by row with an `A` for the `tag` value, which isn't always present.

With that in mind, we need to start by selecting a "seed" row for each `rank`. The easiest way to do this is using the `row_number()` function to sort within each rank and then pick the first row:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by rank order by case when tag = 'A' then 0 when coalesce(tag,'') = '' then 1 else 2 end, tag) as rn
    FROM [table]
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

Now we know which row to use as the base for each rank, but that's not enough. We also need to know about other name values for the same rank. We can find this if we take the first query and `JOIN` it back to the same table based on `rank` again, and then use `GROUP BY` + `STRING_AGG()` to get our final fields. For convenience, I'll use the first query as a CTE:

```
WITH base_rows AS (
    SELECT rank, size, tag, seq, rn
    FROM (
        SELECT *, row_number() over (partition by rank order by case when tag = 'A' then 0 when coalesce(tag,'') = '' then 1 else 2 end, tag) as rn
        FROM [table]
    ) t
    WHERE rn = 1
)
SELECT b.tag, string_agg(t.name,',') names, b.size
FROM base_rows b
INNER JOIN [table] t ON t.rank = b.rank
GROUP BY b.rank, b.tag, b.size, b.seq
ORDER BY b.Seq
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/jt7m_EpK